# How to texture mapping like this?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

[image]

I know how to UV mapping and projection mapping however, in this image, uv mapped using top projection result texture is not bleeding or stretched.

Even side faces is not stretched

I think there's another way to projection uv or another mapping? (Or decal)

I don't know how he made this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming* the topology of the wall is as it appears in your image and that it appears this way in-game, this could be first projected from an orthographic **front** view:

[image]

Then the UV mapping scaled, and the top face manually adjusted to minimize distortion:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*3D game assets have different design constraints than models intended for still or animated 3D art -- it's likely that the horizontal beams of that wall are **not** modeled in, they're from normal maps on a flat-sided wall with a rounded top, and Jachym Michal's answer shows how that was done for in-game.  Also, [your example image is concept art](https://magazine.artstation.com/2021/10/mediatonic-fall-guys-season-5-art-blast/), and the top-down projections shown were likely done in 2D software (moss maps overlaying 2D images of the walls).

Answer (score 2):

No projection magic, just good ol' manual unwrapping.
All texture variants follow the same rules, so one UV map works for all

[image]

Comment: But it's not a flat wall as your answer shows, it has a rounded made-of-logs like shape.  Yet the image isn't distorted by the shape - this indicates projection (from the side IMHO, not the top) to me, assuming that's how it looks in-game instead of just in the 2D concept art.

Comment: On later thought, looking over other images from the article ( https://magazine.artstation.com/2021/10/mediatonic-fall-guys-season-5-art-blast/ ), that part of the walls may be flat with normal maps giving them the made-of-logs look.  In which case your solution would be accurate.